# Joint Distribution and Covariance?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

Problem: Let X be a random variable such that $X \sim N(0, 1)$ Let W be a random variable independent of X such that $\Pr [W = 1] = \Pr [W = −1] = \frac12$. Define Y = XW

Show that X and Y are uncorrelated.

The first part of this problem is to show that X and Y have the same distributions which I understand...but how do I find the co-variance of these when I don't know their joint distribution?

Comment: Typo? $Y = XW$ and not $Y = XY$, right?

Comment: Ah yes my apologies, editing now

Comment: So, what happens if you plug in $Y=XW$ in the formula $\mathrm{Cov}(U,V)=\mathrm{E}[UV]-\mathrm{E}[U]\mathrm{E}[V]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the expectation value of both $X$ and $Y$ is zero, the covariance is given by $\sigma(X,Y)=E(XY)$ which leads to $E(X^2W)=\frac{1}{2}\times1\times E(X^2)+\frac{1}{2}\times(-1)\times E(X^2)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As you know the joint(! - they are independent) distribution of $X$ and $W$, you can compute the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$:

For Borel sets $A$ and $B$ we have
\begin{align*}
  \def\P{\mathbf P}\P(X \in A, Y \in B) 
    &= \P(X \in A, XW \in B)\\
    &= \P(X \in A, XW \in B, W = 1) + \P(X \in A, XW \in B, W = -1)\\
    &= \P(X \in A, X \in B, W = 1) + \P(X \in A, -X \in B, W = -1)\\
    &= \P(X \in A \cap B, W=1) + \P(X \in A \cap (-B), W = -1)\\
    &= \frac 12 \P(X \in A \cap B) + \frac 12\P\bigl(X \in A \cap (-B)\bigr)
\end{align*}
As $X$'s distribution is given, we can read off $(X,Y)$'s.

Answer (score 1):

As @martini points out: the joint distribution is known here.

In general the joint distribution of rv's $U,V$ determines the joint distribution of rv's $f(U,V),g(U,V)$ where $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions.

In your case the joint distribution of $X,W$ is known and we are dealing with functions $(x,w)\mapsto x$ and $(x,w)\mapsto xw$

To find the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ you hardly need this.

Evidently $\mathbb EX\mathbb EY=0\times 0=0$ so that:

$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb EXY=\mathbb EX^2W=\mathbb EX^2\mathbb EW=1\times 0=0$

The third equality is implied by independence.